# counting lines in a file with a filter with clojure

Tags: clojure

I'm trying to figure out what is wrong with my code here. Basically the idea behind it is that I am reading a very large file and at the end of each line in the file is a number. I want to count the number of lines that have the number at the end greater than 500.

What I have is this and on paper it should work, but something is going wrong and I keep returning nil.

```
(defn countlines [] (with-open [rdr (clojure.java.io/reader "myfile.txt")]
(doseq [line (line-seq rdr)]
(count (re-find #"(?!500)[56789]\d{2,}|\d{4,}$" line)))))
```

Comment: @Elogent oops, yeah. For example the line would be like "This line is a bunch of usless stuff 50123" and the line after that would be "This line is also pretty useless 43"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the reason is that you use `doseq`:

clojure.core/doseq
 [seq-exprs & body]
Macro
Added in 1.0
  Repeatedly executes body (presumably for side-effects) with
  bindings and filtering as provided by "for".  Does not retain
  the head of the sequence. **Returns nil.**

you should probably rewrite it to something like `(doall (for [line (line-seq rdr)] ...`

but to fulfill your task you need to rewrite it (because your function would return a seq of counts of chars in matches:

```
user> (count (re-find #"\d+" "123k456"))
3
```

which is obviously not what you want

what you need to do is:

```
(count (filter #(re-find #"(?!500)[56789]\d{2,}|\d{4,}$" %)
               (line-seq rdr)))
```

Comment: I tried that and the console glitched out on me and returned a huge chain of zeroes and 5's...

Comment: never mind, I tried it and I got a reasonable solution. the document is over 10000 lines long and I'm not gonna go through and hand count them all, but it appears to work. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the question correctly, you should be doing something like this:

```
(defn countlines [] (with-open [rdr (clojure.java.io/reader "myfile.txt")]
(-> (line-seq rdr)
    (filter #(re-find #"(?!500)[56789]\d{2,}|\d{4,}$" %))
    (count))))
```

Comment: It's not mandatory to put `count` in parens, btw. https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/-%3E

Answer (score 0):

About Martin Lechner's answer, I think should use Thread last(->>) rather than Thread first(->). So it should be

```
(defn countlines [] (with-open [rdr (clojure.java.io/reader "myfile.txt")] (->> (line-seq rdr)
(filter #(re-find #"(?!500)[56789]\d{2,}|\d{4,}$" %))
(count))))
```